# What is the "right" way to handle GZ when downloading it with PHP

Tags: php, curl, gzip

I am trying to take a link that has a gz file in it with php and decompress into the file in it (XML):

```
http://pricesprodpublic.blob.core.windows.net/pricefull/PriceFull7290027600007-001-201510080331.gz?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=%2FK7fni9kl%2FNukOTnHnW15%2BQue79dbCCFM9vyrOyHfDY%3D&se=2015-10-08T13%3A39%3A44Z&sp=r
```

What is the "right" way of doing it?

I am looking for piece of code that downloads it to the server and opens it.

Comment: What have you discovered so far in your researches? (*not* right is valid too)

Comment: That I can save a file but not sure how to decompress it

Comment: I am looking for piece of code that downloads it to the server and opens it.

Comment: @dreamoki Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. This includes "pieces of code"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading the file I decode it and get it ready to parse it:

```
$file = "http://pricesprodpublic.blob.core.windows.net/pricefull/PriceFull7290027600007-001-201510080331.gz?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=%2FK7fni9kl%2FNukOTnHnW15%2BQue79dbCCFM9vyrOyHfDY%3D&se=2015-10-08T13%3A39%3A44Z&sp=r"
$zdata = file_get_contents($file);

$data =  gzdecode ( $zdata );
echo $data;
```